# How to nest a json object into an empty json object to create a geojson file?

Tags: python, json, geojson

I'm trying to create a geojson file. I have a list of objects and their coordinates in an excel file. I brought in that information into a pandas dataframe and am trying to loop through the records to create a geojson file. I mostly have everything working but I'm trying to match the schema of geojson.io so I can open the file on that platform and make edits to the points and then save again as a geojson file.

I have mostly everything working, but to create the coordinates object, there is 2 brackets before the list of coordinates & I'm having a hard time trying to replicate that in python.

How do I code a nested object into another?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post code in code blocks, not as images.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out! I just needed to discover the geojson package.

[image]